# Search sentence in text file c#

Tags: c#

I want to make a program to search for a sentence but my program can only search for 1 character not a whole sentence. I don't want to use `Contains`. So from here what part of code should I edit? I think my loop have a problem but I can't figure it out

```
class Readfile
{
    public void readf()
    {
        int j;
        int i = 0;
        int flag = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter sentence : ");
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        char[] c1 = str.ToCharArray();
        string filename = @"C: \Users\jan31\Desktop\matthew\text.txt";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            string str2 = sr.ReadToEnd();
            char[] fs = str2.ToCharArray();
            for (i = 0; i < fs.Length; i++) //loop for file
            {
                if (flag == c1.Length)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("found");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    for (j = 0; j < c1.Length;) //loop for user string input
                    {

                        if (c1[j] == fs[i])
                        {
                            flag = flag + 1;
                            j++;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            flag = 0;
                            j = 0;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain why you would prefer all this custom code over Contains?

Comment: Contains would be suggested here.  But look into regular expressions if you want an alternative.

Comment: I think the text file ist to large to search it as one string via contains. It that right?

Comment: Be aware that [identical Unicode strings can have different results when converted to character arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662585/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Line 33, remove the `break` statement and add `i++`. I verified it works. The problem is, you are not progressing with your search when the first character matches.

I suggest that you move this post to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, which looks like a more appropriate place for code reviews.

Comment: Codereview is for working code, this isn't, so stackoverflow is appropriate

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Ohhh Ok I got it Thank you so much :]

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside all the issues of using "contains" or RegEx (either of which would be better and likely faster), the issue in your loop is that you keep resetting the value of "j" back to zero in order to increment "i". Once you find an initial match, you need to increment both the subject and target to determine if the match holds for the next character.

```
    public void readf()
    {
        int j;
        int i;
        var flag = 0;
        var str = "BCD";
        var c1 = str.ToCharArray();

        var str2 = "ABBCDEF";
        var fs = str2.ToCharArray();
        for (i = 0; i < fs.Length; i++) //loop for file
        {
            if (flag == c1.Length) // All characters in the search string where found.
            {
                Console.WriteLine("found");
                break; 
            }
            for (j = 0; j < c1.Length;) //loop for user string input
            {

                if (c1[j] == fs[i + j]) // By evaluating i + j, you don't lose your place within the file. 
                {
                    flag = flag + 1;
                    j++;
                    continue;
                }
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }  // End file loop
        Assert.AreEqual(flag, c1.Length);
    }
```

You'll want to verify your edge cases of course.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation :]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your loop is not correct. Please take a look as my solution bellow:

```
        for (i = 0; i < fs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (c1[0] == fs[i])
            {
                for (var j = 1; j < c1.Length;) //loop for user string input
                {
                    if (c1[j] != fs[i = j])
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("found");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("not found");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to read a file and look for a string while reading it. Maybe bacous you file is to large to read it at once. Here is my solution.

```
    class Readfile
    {
        public static void readf()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter sentence : ");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            string filename = @"C: \Users\jan31\Desktop\matthew\text.txt";
            Encoding fileEncoding = Encoding.Default;
            bool Found = false;
            using (Stream s = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename))
            {
                int current;
                string ReadText = "";
                List<Byte> L = new List<Byte>();
                do
                {
                    current = s.ReadByte();
                    if (current != -1)
                    {
                        L.Add((Byte)current);
                        ReadText = fileEncoding.GetString(L.ToArray());
                        if (ReadText.Length > str.Length)
                        {
                            L.RemoveAt(0);
                            ReadText = fileEncoding.GetString(L.ToArray());
                        }
                        if (ReadText.Length == str.Length)
                        {
                            if (ReadText == str)
                            {
                                //Found it ##############
                                Found = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } while ((current != -1) && !Found);
            }
            if (!Found) {
                //Not Found it ##############
            }
        }
    }
```