# Same Korean string compares false

Tags: python, unicode

file_list is a list of file names in Korean.
I checked 0th index of file_list and it prints '윤균상.jpg' string
but above code,
file_list[0] == '윤균상.jpg'
returns false.. Why is this?

```py
print(file_list[0] == '윤균상.jpg')
print(file_list[0])
```

first line prints "False"
and the second line prints "윤균상.jpg" which is string

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662585/how-do-i-compare-a-unicode-string-that-has-different-bytes-but-the-same-value solve your problem?

Comment: probably one is created from Jamos and the other contains Hangeul characters directly. Always normalize the string before comparing