# Python Dataframe loc : KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

```
df = pd.read_excel(excelName)               
df.columns=df.columns.str.strip()
print(df.columns.tolist())
# print result is ['序号', '学号', '姓名', '文件位置', '邮箱地址']
print(df.loc['文件位置'])
```

It seems I have the column named '文件位置'
But when I locate this column by loc, it raises key error.

Comment: Hey, check the exact column name in excel. Sometimes, these columns appear slightly different on IDE Or if you could share the link of the excel.

Comment: This might be helpful: [How do I compare a Unicode string that has different bytes, but the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49662585/354577)

Comment: A very late reply, but `loc` allows indexing in both dimensions. The format is `df.loc[row_indexer, col_indexer]`. `df['文件位置']` would be equivalent to `df.loc[:, '文件位置']` _not_ `df.loc['文件位置']` which is looking for a _row_ labeled '文件位置' not a column. This is covered in the accepted answer of the linked duplicate.