# How do you make conditional statements using different languages such as Arabic in Python?

Tags: python, arabic

So I'm trying to loop through an Arabic string then if the letter is a certain value the code does something so the conditional statement would look something like this:

```py
if a[i]=="و":
    # Expecting to get this executed but it doesn't even when the letter is same
    # Further logic down ahead.
```

The only issue is that the conditional doesn't run even when the value is that letter. How would I go round doing this?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] showing your problem. I don't know anything about how arabic gets encoded, but maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662585/how-do-i-compare-a-unicode-string-that-has-different-bytes-but-the-same-value is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your editor supports utf-8. The code below works well for me:

```
a = 'abcوdef'

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == 'و':
        print(f"'{a[i]}' match")
```

Output:

```
'و' match
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert those into unicode code number and then compare it like below with the help of `ord` inbuilt function in python. It also returns `True` when the condition is met.

```py
given_letter = 'و'
print(ord(given_letter[0]) ==  ord('و'))
True
```

Comment: This can't make things better. Consider `print(ord('炙'), ord('炙'))`, that outputs `28825 63995` though the characters are identical - but can be obtained by different unicode code points. The OP's problem, which we can't know exactly as he didn't provide a [mre], might be caused by just that, so the solution probably has to do with unicode normalization, see the link in my comment under the question.